# Is it correct to say that any "Basis of accounting" is a database that can be used to create a Trial balance?

Tags: accounting, terminology

I try to learn about some fundamental terms in *account management* and I have a trouble understanding the difference between the following two terms:

In English Wikipedia, a [Basis of accounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_of_accounting) is currently defined as:

> The time various financial transactions are recorded

I would interpret that this is a variable with one or more value/s while each value is a time of a deal done with a certain type of payment (both the time and payment type are recorded).

Is it correct to say that any "Basis of accounting" is a database that can be used to create a "Trial balance" (which I understand to be a database by itself, comprised of all *accounts* from a general ledger)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It says: The basis of accounting is the **time** when various financial transactions are recorded.

Then it says the main ones are the **cash basis** and **accrual basis**.

The **cash basis** means you record the transaction when you get/pay the money. In business terms, "cash" doesn't only mean bank notes and coins - it means any kind of money, including bank notes, coins, bank deposits, cryptocurrency, and so on.

The **accrual basis** means you record the transaction when you sell or buy the product, even if you haven't got/paid the money yet.

It is literally what it says. The basis of accounting is the rule you use to decide when to record a transaction. It is not a database.

Comment: Perhaps because I am not a native English speaker I grasped cash as "bank notes" and didn't imagine any other possible meaning, such as "immediate payment"; cash means "immediate" here and "accrual" means "some kind of a lone" here, then I guess I understand it better now.

Comment: Bank notes and coins*

Comment: @George It does mean bank notes and coins. With the cash basis, you record the transaction when you get the bank notes and coins. "Accrue"/"accrual" is a harder word - it is meaning 1 on [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accrue)

Comment: So, why say these two are primary? AFAIK, payment with QR codes and/or debit/credit cards are not only immediate but more common than cash in some countries.

Comment: @George they weren't common when the name "cash basis" was invented

Comment: Of course, I find it odd Wikipedia mentions them as such (or could be understood doing so): `are the two primary methods of tracking income and expenses in accounting`.

Comment: Electronic movement of cash is still cash; 'Cash Basis' doesn't just mean paper notes and coins.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon depends on context

Comment: In reference to the latest edit - no, Cryptocurrency is not considered cash, in any accounting system I am aware of. Just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the next part of the quote.

[Basis of accounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_of_accounting)

> A basis of accounting is the time various financial transactions are
> recorded. The cash basis (EU VAT vocabulary cash accounting) and the
> accrual basis are the two primary methods of tracking income and
> expenses in accounting.

In the United States, and many other places in the world, people use a cash basis for their accounting.

For example on one of the first days of 2020 I receive a paycheck for the the time card I submitted in late December 2019. Under cash accounting the money is assigned to the 2020 tax year. If I was using accrual accounting the work was done in December so the early 2020 paycheck would still be assigned to toe 2019 tax year.

The basis of accounting isn't a database, it is the foundation of rules that is used to assign the events to various periods.

Answer (score 0):

A company has a single basis of accounting.  Think of the basis of accounting as a variable with 1 of a very small number of allowed values.  In 99% of cases, that value is one of two possibilities-- cash or accrual.

In the vast majority of cases, companies (particularly public companies) use an accrual basis of accounting.  They recognize income and expenses when they are incurred not when they actually send or receive cash.  If a window washing company washes the windows on a skyscraper, they'll account for the income when the work is complete and they send the invoice to the building owner rather than when the building owner eventually pays them.  In the vast majority of cases, individuals use a cash basis of accounting.  The employee of the window washing company that actually washes the windows accounts for her income when her income arrives in her account rather than accounting for the income she earns each day.

In general, accrual accounting provides a better overall picture of the financial state of the entity since it accounts for income and expenses that are expected and since it tends to smooth out the bumpiness of cash payments.  On the other hand, accrual accounting is more complicated to deal with so it is easier to maintain books via cash accounting.